# Centre div inside wrapper with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I wish to centre a wrapper div of fixed width (wrapper) inside another div (body) as you can see below.
[image]

The line represents the centre of the page/browser window, and as you can see, it both the body and the centre of the wrapper are centred in the middle of the page.

Is there a way to accomplish this using pure CSS and HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone bothered to write a short and descriptive *How To* to this common issue: http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

You have two items to position in there, so you'll need apply the technique twice, but you can't really center the body element with this so you'll need to add another container instead of the body.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

you could always try.

```
margin: auto;
```

This will only work with a doctype.  So put this above your html tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using the standard wrapping function which was given above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#bodywrapper { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }
#wrapper { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="bodywrapper">
        .....whatever code you in the body here.
    <div id="wrapper>
          ....whatever you want inside the wrapper that is inside the body here.
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, you are just nesting a wrapper within a wrapper. There's no reason this can't be done.