# Align part of an image

Tags: html, css, alignment

I would like to use a very wide image on my website. There is one main item on the image, the rest is sort of a background. But I would like this main item to be aligned at all times, while the image should show the more or less background depending on how wide the window size is...

I've tried to make it clear in an image:
[image]

So, the red border is the whole image (it had a width of 4000px) but it has only one main item on it. In my case a photo of a girl. The background (everything inside the red border besides the green border) is filled with some flowers. What I want is to be the girl (green border) to be aligned in the middle by all means. And depending on the size of the window, the flowers should be more or less visible (but without a scrollingbar).

But I don't have any idea how to do this... Anyone with advice?

[image]

Comment: +1 for the beautiful rendition of Mona Lisa you have there.

Comment: Haha, lol :) Thanks for the compliment!

Comment: i would separate the image in two parts - flowers - to be used as a bg on the centre div/table
and the main picture that would go into that div/table as `<img>`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option since the image of the girl and the image of the flowers are one image and they can't be seperated

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039583/centre-div-inside-wrapper-with-overflow-hidden

Comment: `#window{background: url('path/to/image.jpg') center center};`

Comment: please provide the image so i can show you the desired output. If you have your code in which you are facing problem then you can show us code also..please.

Comment: I added the image... The red block should be 960px wide and only this should be aligned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a single decorative image, then you can use:

```
background-image: url(whole.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat
```

Adjust the first percentage if your interesting part of the image is not exactly in the center.

If you'd like to use a separate `<img>` for the girl, and separate image for the flowers, then use [one of the usual vertical-CSS-centering hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+center+css) for the `<img>` e.g.

```
#container {position:relative; overflow:hidden}
#container img {position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; 
    margin-top:-half-of-image-in-px; margin-left:-half-of-the-image-in-px;}
```

and the former style for the background.

If you want to be cutting-edge, you can use [CSS3 object-fit property](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a single image... If I understand correctly, the css of above will align the image 50% to the left and 50% to the right, right? But what if the image is 4000px wide and the window only 1000px?

Comment: @Michiel background-position with `%` aligns point at given percentage in the image with point with same percentage in the container, so `50%` aligns middle of the image with middle of the container — i.e. centers it perfectly in all cases.

Comment: I tried your first line of code, but with no luck... Maybe you'll get better what I mean if you see my image in my original post...

Comment: Great, thanks. But the red border should be displaying always the same... Now, the content is just sliding when you resize the window

Comment: @Michiel: If you *don't* want background centered and would prefer fixed top/left edge then instead of `50%` use fixed (negative) offset in `px` (centering means edges will slide as the frame moves)

Answer (score 0):

If the girl is at the center of the picture this shouldn't be a problem. Just use the image as the `background-image` of your `body`. With CSS3 you can make it so that the background is resized to the full width of the screen. Use `background-size: contain;` if the aspect ratio of the container equals the ratio of the image. If it is not, and you still wish to fill the whole window without clipping the image, use `background-size: cover;`. Another possibility is to use `background-size: 100% auto;`.

Read more about CSS3 background-size [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)

Ideally, it would be better to have the girl as a seperate image and the background as a pattern, so you could use the pattern with a repeat-x and the girl on a different container, even though you can have multiple backgrounds with CSS3. BUT, by doing so (i.e. different containers for the different backgrounds) you will have better cross-browser support.